# Conditional testing

Tags: javascript, css, cypress

In my tests, I want to change the background depending on its current wallpaper. To do this I use conditional testing:

```js
it("change the wallpaper", () => {
  if (wallpaperPage.backgroundImage().should('have.css', 'background', 'rgb(38, 167, 223) url("https://url.com/ck/img/common/wallpapers/wallpaper_1.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% / 120px padding-box border-box')) {
    wallpaperPage.purpleColorButton().click({force: true});
    wallpaperPage.cloudsButton().click({force: true});
    wallpaperPage.backgroundImage().should('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(143, 40, 140)');
    wallpaperPage.backgroundImage().should('have.css', 'background-image', 'url("https://url.com/ck/img/common/wallpapers/wallpaper_2.png")');
  
  } else {
    wallpaperPage.blueColorButton().click({force: true});
    wallpaperPage.watermelonsButton().click({force: true});
    wallpaperPage.backgroundImage().should('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(38, 167, 223)');
    wallpaperPage.backgroundImage().should('have.css', 'background-image', 'url("https://url.com/ck/img/common/wallpapers/wallpaper_1.png")');
  }
})
```

html code of background element I want to check:

```html
<div data-v-6dfe149e="" class="wallpaper-background screen__preview" style="background-size: 120px; background-image: url(&quot;https://url.com/ck/img/common/wallpapers/wallpaper_2.png&quot;); background-color: rgb(143, 40, 140);"></div>
```

The problem with the code is that it works only for a 'true' statement. Otherwise, when the 'if' condition is false the test fails. I guess it's because there's a 'should' assertion but I have no idea how to get rid of it and check 'have.css' without it. Any ideas?

Comment: try to paste all html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to extract the 'background' value for comparison. In the below snippet, `$el` is a jquery (cypress automatically includes jquery) instance which is used to get the 'background' value.

```
it("change the wallpaper", () => {
  wallpaperPage.backgroundImage().then($el => {
    const background = $el.css('background');
    if (background === 'rgb(38, 167, 223) url("https://url.com/ck/img/common/wallpapers/wallpaper_1.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% / 120px padding-box border-box') {
      wallpaperPage.purpleColorButton().click({force: true});
      wallpaperPage.cloudsButton().click({force: true});
      wallpaperPage.backgroundImage().should('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(143, 40, 140)');
      wallpaperPage.backgroundImage().should('have.css', 'background-image', 'url("https://url.com/ck/img/common/wallpapers/wallpaper_2.png")');
    } else {
      wallpaperPage.blueColorButton().click({force: true});
      wallpaperPage.watermelonsButton().click({force: true});
      wallpaperPage.backgroundImage().should('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(38, 167, 223)');
      wallpaperPage.backgroundImage().should('have.css', 'background-image', 'url("https://url.com/ck/img/common/wallpapers/wallpaper_1.png")');
    }
  });
})
```